# Pulling Redux data with userID param error - React / Node / Express

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am trying to pull a log of user data belonging to userID from my backend in React. The backend API is working correctly with Postman however I can't get this working with the userID. It is console logging the correctly userID in the component however I am yet to get a Thunk Redux store data working with a param passed in.

Is there anywhere obvious I am going wrong from looking at the code below? I have had my Redux working previously with data not using a param so I know it is not an issue with my store / redux index etc.

component

```
const userDiveLogList = useSelector(state => state.user.userDiveLogList);

    const [userDiveLog, setUserDiveLog] = useState({
        userDiveLogList: [],
        expanded: false
    })
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(requireUserDiveLogData(user.userID));
    }, []);
```

action

```
// load a users diveLog
export const requireUserDiveLogData = createAsyncThunk('diveLog/requireData', 
    async (userID, thunkAPI) => {
        const response = await userDiveLogList(userID);
        return response.data;
    },
    {
        condition: (_, { getState }) => {
            const { user } = getState(); 
            if (user.didLoadData) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
)
```

reducer

```
export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: {
        userDiveLogList: [],
        didLoadData: false,
    },
    reducers: {
        [requireUserDiveLogData.pending.type]: (state) => {
            state.didLoadData = true;
        },
        [requireUserDiveLogData.fulfilled.type]: (state, action) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload
            }
        },
```

service

```
// returns list of dives per user from db
export const userDiveLogList  = (userID) => {
        return axios.get(API_URL + `userdiveloglist/${userID}`);
    };
```

**Update**

Does this have something to do with my action call for when data gets called if it is already called? I have the getState condition const as userDiveLog when it is in the user branch and it is user/userDiveLogList in the branch, it is also named userDiveLogList when it is being sent at the backend. I can see the backend request being made for the correct user number but nothing is returning.

Comment: So you've verified that the API call looks correct from the browser network tab?

Comment: What other debugging have you done? Have you followed  `userID` from `dispatch(requireUserDiveLogData(user.userID));` to `userDiveLogList.fetchById(userID)` in the asynchronous action? Where does the code go from here? Where is `userID` possibly dropped? Where does the execution flow break unexpectedly?

Comment: It is returning Network Error at the minute. In the backend does it matter that my param is userId and not userID? I can't get the userID to work for some reason.

Comment: Based on the code that you've posted here it should be `await userDiveLogList(userID)` instead of `await userDiveLogList.fetchById(userID)`.  But your errors would be different if that were the problem, so I think you copy & pasted wrong?

Comment: I found the cause of the user route problem. I just had to fix my file names as the user at the start was picking up the access control that I hadn't implemented yet. If my console.logs in the action and service files are not being printed for userID does this mean that wherever the problem is that those files aren't being accessed? do I have the use ${userID} in the action?

Comment: I had went off the examples on the site. They also said to add a ThunkAPI , is this needed?